# How to compile MySQL (Percona) with jemalloc installed under custom prefix?

Tags: mysql, percona

My **jemalloc** is installed under `/opt/jemalloc`, how to compile MySQL/Percona with the support of jemalloc?

The standard option is

```
cmake . -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS='-ljemalloc'  -DWITH_SAFEMALLOC=OFF
```

But how about my case since they are in custom path?

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this one out? I saw this post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/percona-discussion/nHvg9_g3DuU which makes me thing I should compile without jemalloc and then just change the config later, but I don't know if this is good or not.